# send post respond in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I have used bcrypt to encrypt the password in my signup process..Here is my login code..I want to send a respond only if the password and email are correct.If the email is wrong it gives an alert- "fail"..If all are correct it gives an alert-"success".But In this code if password is wrong it doesn't send nothing and I cant use an alert for that..How can I send a respond with nothing to get that alert?

This is my reactjs code .....

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/reg/getuser",
{
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(user)
})
.then(function(response)
{
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data,props)
{
    if(data.length == 0)
    {
        console.log("damn");
        window.alert('Login Failed!')
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("done");
        window.alert('Login Successful!');
    }
});
```

This is my nodejs code...

```
router.post('/getuser',function(req,res)
{
    Customer.find({email:req.body.email})
    .then(function(details){
        if(details.length<1)
        {
            res.send(details)
        }
        else
        {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,details[0].password,(err,result)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }

                if(result){
                    res.send(details)
                }
                // here,when password is wrong...want to send a respond as
                // data.length==0 (in fetch)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please use StackOverflow for adding media resources or anything related to question, third-party resources may become invalid after some time. You should use third-party tools only to give more reference and example for the question which can't be put on the StackOverflow itself.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  The policy here is that any code required to understand the question must be pasted into the question itself as text (not only on an external link) and then formatted properly as code.  This is because external resources have a habit of getting changed over time or event disappearing and stack overflow strides to be a long term searchable resource library of solutions.

Comment: There's no `else` case for `if (result)` in your node.js code. I'd guess that's what would be executed if the password was wrong? Or is your point that you're trying to send an empty response if the password is wrong? I'd be very surprised if node.js didn't send that correctly - can you verify that in your browser debug tools?

Comment: @Rup yes. in else case for If(result) I should send a respond as data.length==0..how can i do it??

Comment: [This site](https://flaviocopes.com/express/#use-end-to-send-an-empty-response) says you can just use `res.end()`, but I don't know express well enough to comment, sorry.

Comment: @Rup Thanku so much..Then can u tell another way to validate email & password here??

Answer (score 1):

On a authentification you should work with a correct status code.
You can set your status-code with `res.status(200).send('loggedin')`.

Use following status-codes:

**200** - to say ok login was successful

**400** or **401** - to say auth has failed.

To show the error message or to redirect the user check the status-code from your ajax request and do your stuff.

**Edit** fixed client snippet.

client

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/reg/getuser",
{
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(user)
})
.then(function(response)
{   
    if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("ok");
        console.log(response.json());
        window.alert('Login successfull!')
    } else {
        console.log("damn");
        window.alert('Login Failed!')
    }
})
.catch(function() {
    console.log('error handling');
});
```

server

```js
router.post('/getuser',function(req,res)
{
    Customer.find({email:req.body.email})
    .then(function(details){
        if(details.length<1)
        {
            res.status(400).send(details)
        }
        else
        {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,details[0].password,(err,result)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }

                if(result){
                    return res.status(200).send(details);
                    // return res.status(200).json(details); Use this line to send a json if result is an object.
                }

                return res.status(400).send('login failed');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: omg..!! It works well..so much helpful..Thank u so much ..!! :D :D